# How to create an item XP based leveling system for Discord game bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot that is essentially a remake of RuneScape (learning JavaScript right now and RS is my favorite game :P). You type in command /mine and it mines some ores for you. I have it to where there is a /help command and /mine command. I'm looking to add an item XP based leveling system. Each "ore" (item you're mining) has a set XP value so for example, Dirt = 5XP and Stone = 10XP so each time I mine a piece of stone I get 10XP and then it adds up until I reach the level mark. Level 1-10 is 1000XP and it exponentially gets larger on a scale of 1.5 I'm just not sure how to implement this into the program.

I'm only been using JavaScript and Discord.js for a few months, so please don't roast my code too hard haha.

Here is the program:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const dirt = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + " <:dirt:679475976274575391> Dirt");
const stone = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + " <:stone:679476006758907904> Stone");
const ores = [dirt, stone];

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Connected as " + client.user.tag)
})

client.on('message', (receivedMessage) => {
    if (receivedMessage.author == client.user) {
        return
    }

    if (receivedMessage.content.startsWith("/")) {
        processCommand(receivedMessage)
    }
})


function processCommand(receivedMessage) {
    let fullCommand = receivedMessage.content.substr(1)
    let splitCommand = fullCommand.split(" ")
    let primaryCommand = splitCommand[0]
    let arguments = splitCommand.slice(1)

    console.log("Command received: " + primaryCommand)
    console.log("Arguments: " + arguments)

    if (primaryCommand == "help") {
        helpCommand(receivedMessage)
    } else if (primaryCommand == "mine") {
        mineCommand(receivedMessage)
    } else if (primaryCommand == "level") {
        levelCommand(receivedMessage)
    }
}



function randomOre() {
    return ores[Math.floor(Math.random() * ores.length)];
}

function ore() {
    if (randomOre() == dirt) {
        return (dirt)
    } else if (randomOre() == stone) {
        return (stone)
    } else if (randomOre() == dirt && stone) {
        return (dirt + "\n" + stone)
    }
}

function helpCommand(receivedMessage) {
    const helpEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Help')
        .setAuthor('Virtual Miner')
        .setDescription('List of all available commands here.')
        .addField(name='**/mine**', value='Allows users to mine for ores and collect them.')
        .addField('/shop - Gives users access to the shop where you can buy better pickaxes, upgrades, boosts, and minecarts.')
        .setFooter('Virtual Miner | Made by Aqyl#0093')

    receivedMessage.channel.send(helpEmbed)
}

function mineCommand(receivedMessage) {
    user = receivedMessage.member.user.tag;

    const mineEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setAuthor(user)
        .addField(name="**You found: **", value=ore())
        .setFooter('Virtual Miner | Made by Aqyl#0093')

    receivedMessage.channel.send(mineEmbed)
}

bot_secret_token = "*********************************************"

client.login(bot_secret_token)
```

Either documentation, videos, or just a plain old explanation would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Please use a seperate config file (you can use json) to store the bot's token, load it into a variable and use that to log in. Don't post your token online, if it ever leaks (like it did right now) refresh it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [this tutorial](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html#file-overview) from `discordjs guide` as it teaches you how to build a currency system. You can adapt the code and change it into a message based experience system with a little work.

it uses a `Sequelize V5` database to store the data for it